# Image height in IE7

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer-7

I've been trying to create a stretchable background image by absolutely positioning an `img` tag and giving it a width and a height of 100% as so:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="background">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" width="100%" height="100%" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 1px solid green;" />
    </div>
    <span class="text">
        aaa bbb ccc ddd
    </span>
</div>
```

This works fine in IE8+, Chrome and Firefox, but unfortunately I need to support IE 7 as well.

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zPcwC/5/) demonstrates the problem: The image is resized to fit 100% width, but its aspect ratio is preserved, as such:

[image: Screenshot]

How do I cause the image to be exactly the same size as the containing div? Note that if I give the containing div (`.background`) a fixed size, the problem is resolved, but that defeats the purpose of having it resized according to the text.

Comment: Do you want the result like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zPcwC/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/cqTTm/

Tested in IE7/8/9, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera.

The `*property` rules are only applied to IE7.

```
.item {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
.background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    *height: 100%
}
.text {
    position: relative;
}
```

On `.background`, plain `height: 100%` might be usable instead of `*height: 100%`. I left it applying to the only browser that needs it (IE7) to avoid having to retest in all those browsers again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the height (and width, prolly) on the containing div as well, not just the image:

```
.background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%; /*This is the important bit */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zPcwC/9/

Also, proving that it still works when the text fills up:

http://jsfiddle.net/zPcwC/10/

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly, this breaks in Chrome and Firefox. I've updated it to use horribly broken CSS that only IE understands to fix that - http://jsfiddle.net/zPcwC/11/

Comment: @configurator wow, that is odd. hurray for IE7's asterik, though. :)

Comment: @configurator your code breaks with my test cases (in everything but IE7), not sure if it matters: http://jsfiddle.net/zPcwC/14/

Comment: @thirtydot: Thanks for letting me know. Important thing is, adding the `width` and `height` to my project didn't break in any browser so I'm happy :)

Comment: @thirtydot: I see your answer now; it's very similar to the code I actually have in my project - especially the inline-block part.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do this?

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="background">
    aaa bbb ccc ddd
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, in your css, you could put

```
.background {
  background: transparent url(placeholder.jpg) no-repeat top left;
}
```

This way, the image is fixed as a background image in the .background div. The content within the background div will stretch it, reveiling only a part of the background image.

Is this what you are asking?

Comment: No, this doesn't stretch the background image, this only crops it.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Sorry I couldn't be of any help.